# How does courier flaps mistakenly ships Jerry to Birdperson on S2E10

Tags: plot-explanation, rick-and-morty

As the *Rick and Morty* episode S2E10 starts the courier flaps brings Rick a wedding invitation from Birdperson and for some reason mistakenly ships Jerry to the sender.

This is how it goes:

> Rick: What do you know about friendship, Jerry?
>   courier flaps: Confirmed, shipping Jerry!

I don't understand how this wrong order was inferred from what Rick said?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't get it because you understand that Rick was asking a question to Jerry. The courier, however, took the words at face value and listened for command it was capable of responding to.

> Rick: (What do you know about friend) **ship Jerry**
>   Courier: Confirmed, shipping Jerry!

It's just a really dumb AI who responded to a basic command without observing the context in which it was said.